# Programmatically setting video_embed_field URL

Tags: 8, nodes, media

I am trying to populate nodes programmatically from a feed (migrating earlier site to Drupal 9). So far I have managed to get everything else to move, but I can't figure out, how to set video_embed_field or rather the URL-value of the video. I found an example, but it caters just youtube, but there are also other video providers used.

I have tried the following ideas:

```
$node->set("field_video", $videourl);

$node->field_video = ['input' => $videourl];

$node->field_video = ['value' => $videourl];
```

but so far nothing works.

Could anyone hint me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the last try in my choices seems to work after all.

```
 $node->field_video = ["value" => $item["video"]];
```

I must have done something dumb with my editor like not saving the changes...
Well, maybe someone else finds the info here...